# ValueError: time data '19 November 2022' does not match format '%d/%m/%Y' (match)

Tags: pandas

I am trying a column of type O to dates. e.g

```
Timestamp
19 November 2022
1 May 2022
```

using this formula

```
df['Timestamp'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Timestamp'], format = "%d/%m/%Y")
```

but I receive the error

```
ValueError: time data '19 November 2022' does not match format '%d/%m/%Y' (match)
```

How can I get this date format

Timestamp

```
19/11/2022
1/05/2022
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use %B instead of %m here.

```
df['date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['date'], dayfirst=True, format='%d %B %Y')
```

Also the format variable in the function is for the input not the output. Its essentially telling pandas that this is the format of the input.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `dt.strftime` to convert datetime to other formats (note that then `dtype` of column of other format will be `object` (`string`))

```py
import pandas

df = pd.DataFrame({"Timestamp": ['19 November 2022', '1 May 2022']})
df


           Timestamp
0   19 November 2022
1         1 May 2022
```

```py
df['Timestamp'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Timestamp'])
df

   Timestamp
0 2022-11-19
1 2022-05-01
```

```py
df['Timestamp2'] = df['Timestamp'].dt.strftime('%-d/%m/%Y')
df

   Timestamp  Timestamp2
0 2022-11-19  19/11/2022
1 2022-05-01   1/05/2022
```

Add a `-` in the date format to remove the leading zero.